# how to run web application from visual studio code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

> I have created an empty web application in visual studio code. But when running it using "dotnet run" it is not opening any browser 
>   it is only showing the below lines.

```
>C:\Users\viru babu\Documents\MVCcoreLinkdin>dotnet run
   >Hosting environment: Production
   >Content root path: C:\Users\viru babu\Documents\MVCcoreLinkdin
   >Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
   >Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

[image]

Comment: did you try to open the address http://localhost:5000 in the browser?

Comment: @ztadic91 ,now i tried and its working ,but why its not opening automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To open the browser automatically on `http://localhost:5000` you can **add a configuration** to your `launch.json`. Add a configuration like this:

```json
{
    "name": "Chrome",
    "type": "chrome",
    "runtimeExecutable": "./path/to/chrome.exe",
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "http://localhost:5000",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",          // maybe you need to adjust this entry to "C:\Users\viru babu\Documents\MVCcoreLinkdin"
    "preLaunchTask": "shell: dotnet run"           // add prelaunch task  start (defined in tasks.json)
}
```

to also launch your application automatically you use the `preLaunchTask`. To do that you need to configure a [custom task](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) in the `tasks.json` that runs your command `dotnet run`.